# Getting other aliases for account names

Tags: windows, system, alias, account, sid

The `SYSTEM` account in Windows has an SID of `S-1-5-18`. It also has an alias of `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. I can query for system account names in the Windows terminal using:

`C:\Windows\system32>wmic sysaccount get name`

This query will return `SYSTEM` as part of the system accounts, but how can I get other aliases for this account, such as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`? Is there a standard way to do this in Windows?

I have only had success in doing this using the [psgetsid](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897417.aspx) tool from SysInternals:

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\PSTools>psgetsid SYSTEM

PsGetSid v1.44 - Translates SIDs to names and vice versa
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SID for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:
S-1-5-18
```

Answer (score 1):

[Greg Zakharov shed some light on this for me and he should take full credit for this answer](http://forum.sysinternals.com/getting-other-aliases-for-account-names_topic31159.html):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace SIDTranslation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    NTAccount account = new NTAccount(Console.ReadLine());
                    IdentityReference identity = account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                    Console.WriteLine("SID for {0}" + Environment.NewLine + "{1}", identity.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)), identity);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As an example, running and typing in `SYSTEM` produces the following output:

```
SID for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
S-1-5-18
```

The account name is essentially translated from its partial NTAccount format to its SID, and then back again in order to produce the full NTAccount name. I'm not entirely sure why this works, but it does.

Comment: `S-1-5` is "NT AUTHORITY", so you just want the full name. This shouldn't be confused with an actual alias (local group) such as `BUILTIN\Administrators`.

Comment: @eryksun Do you happen to know if there is any publication out there that contains information on how SID prefixes map to specific names like how `S-1-5` maps to `NT AUTHORITY`?

Comment: See [Well-known SIDs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Well-Known SID Structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980032.aspx).

Comment: FYI, to view the SIDs and privileges in your current access token check `whoami /all /fo list` and `whoami /logonid`. Or use Sysinternals `accesschk -q -p -f [PID]` to check a given process ID.